# Set cookie using cookie.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm trying to make the page remember the event that was fired by clicking on a radio button using [jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) but it's not saving the cookie.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="foo" name="langs" value="fooval">
<input type="radio" id="bar" name="langs" value="barval">
<span class="foo">Foo</span>

<span class="bar">Bar</span>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input').change(

    function () {

        var closed = $('span').is(":hidden");
        if ($(this).val() == "barval") {
            $('.foo').fadeOut();
            $('.bar').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.bar').fadeOut();
            $('.foo').fadeIn();
        }

        setCookie("open", closed, 365);
    });

    var showsqux = getCookie("open");
    if (showqux == "true") {
        $('.foo').fadeOut();
        $('.bar').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.bar').fadeOut();
        $('.foo').fadeIn();
    }
});


function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.bar {
    display:none
}
```

[CodePen DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HAkuG)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don’t see `jquery.cookie.js` being used in that code anywhere.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, it's used in the Demo, I can add a link in the html code if it's necessary. I honestly thought it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var show **s** qux

```
var showsqux = getCookie("open");
```

if (showqux == "true") {

```
if (showqux == "true") {
```

Darn those typos. :P

Answer (score 1):

Try to steer clear of using cookies, as it's an outdated standard.

WebStorage is the new HTML5 standard which I would recommend and you can here store data of up to 10mb either permanently or simply for that session of viewing.

You can get & set data here with one of two simple commands: 'getItem' or 'setItem'

See for more detail: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp